# Excel function for replacing empty cells with values from neighboring cells

Tags: excel

In excel, I'm tring replace empty cell values in one column with values from another column from the same spreadsheet is this posible?

I tried find and replace, conditional formatating,and data validation with no success
Could someone explain what steps of formula I need to take to perform this task in Excel or do I need to use a different platform.

Comment: Show a screenshot, then explain what you want?

Comment: You cannot do this with a formula in the cell. You could do this in another column or you could use VBA or Power Query. You could also place a formula in just the blank cells as outlined by @BDT below, depending on your actual needs.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say the data with blanks are in `B2:B100`, and the data you want are in `F2:F100`. The first option is probably what you want, but I also added a note about a common data issue.

### How to replace all blank cells with the value from another column

- Select `B2:B100`
- In the **Home** section of the ribbon, click **Find & Select** > **Go To Special...**
- Select **Blanks** then click **OK**.

  - At this point, only the blank cells in column B should be selected. If you see what looks like a blank cell and it's *not* selected, that's a different issue (see below).
- Press the **=** key, then **right arrow** until you get to column F (or wherever the data are that you want). But, *do not press Enter* like you normally would to enter a formula.

  - If the first blank cell was `B8`, the formula bar would now show `=F8`
- Instead of pressing Enter, press **Ctrl + Enter**. This will put that formula in all blank cells at the same time, with each referencing their respective cells in column F.

#### Convert references to values

If you only want the values from column F, not references to the cells in column F, overwrite Column B with its values by following these steps:

- Select all of Column B
- Press **Ctrl + c** (copy)
- Press **Ctrl + Alt + v** (paste special)
- Press **v** (values), then **Enter** and **Esc**

### If Excel isn't seeing empty cells as blank

If you see a cell (e.g., cell `B4`) that *looks* blank, but Excel doesn't select it, that probably means the cell has a zero-length text string (or perhaps some spaces). To test this, pick a different cell and enter

`=ISBLANK(B4)`

If that returns `FALSE`, it means `B4` isn't *really* blank, even though it looks that way to humans. To solve that, I'd probably create a new column and try using a formula that looks like this:

`=IF(LEN(B4) > 0, B4, F4)`

However, there a several other approaches depending on your data.